# How to create a fixed height on expanding dropdown

Tags: html, css

My content is expanding as I click and I was wondering if there was some way to set a fixed `height` on a vertical dropdown.

i tried displaying a block on my `nav` but no luck creating a fixed `height`.

```css
nav {
 overflow: auto;
 display: block;
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GqmEAq)

Comment: take a look at this http://osvaldas.info/drop-down-navigation-responsive-and-touch-friendly

Comment: this is using the `max-height` leb.c mentioned with `overflow: auto` (which was missing in you codepen btw). have a look: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBwEvz

Comment: @marczking thank you that was what I needed

Comment: I added the comment as an answer so you can mark this question as solved

Answer (score 0):

try something like `max-height: 100px;`

Answer (score 0):

this is using the `max-height` leb.c mentioned with `overflow: auto` (which was missing in you codepen btw).

have a look: [codepen.io/anon/pen/zBwEvz](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zBwEvz)